# New named entity class in Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I need to train Spacy NER to be able to recognize 2 new classes for named entity recognition, all I have are files with list of items that are supposed to be in new classes.

For example: Rolling Stones, Muse, Arctic Monkeys - artists
Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a perfect use case for [Matcher](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/rule-based-matching) or [PhraseMatcher](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/matcher.pyx#L496) (if you care about performance).

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

def merge_phrases(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    '''
    Merge a phrase. We have to be careful here because we'll change the token indices.
    To avoid problems, merge all the phrases once we're called on the last match.
    '''
    if i != len(matches)-1:
        return None
    spans = [(ent_id, label, doc[start : end]) for ent_id, label, start, end in matches]
    for ent_id, label, span in spans:
        span.merge('NNP' if label else span.root.tag_, span.text, nlp.vocab.strings[label])


matcher = spacy.matcher.Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add(entity_key='1', label='ARTIST', attrs={}, specs=[[{spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'Rolling'}, {spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'Stones'}]], on_match=merge_phrases)
matcher.add(entity_key='2', label='ARTIST', attrs={}, specs=[[{spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'Muse'}]], on_match=merge_phrases)
matcher.add(entity_key='3', label='ARTIST', attrs={}, specs=[[{spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'Arctic'}, {spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'Monkeys'}]], on_match=merge_phrases)
doc = nlp(u'The Rolling Stones are an English rock band formed in London in 1962. The first settled line-up consisted of Brian Jones, Ian Stewart, Mick Jagger, Keith Richards, Bill Wyman and Charlie Watts')
matcher(doc)
for ent in doc.ents:
  print(ent)
```

See the documentation for more details. From my experience, with 400k entities in a Matcher it would take almost a second to match each document. 
PhraseMatcher is much much faster but a bit trickier to use. Note that this is "strict" matcher, it won't match any entities it haven't seen before.

Comment: but it looks like that i need to add all elements of my new entity manually?

Comment: Right, like I said. If you want to match entities it haven't seen before – you need to train it first, which is more complicated and still requires you to have a LOT of data.

Comment: Please, make sure to accept the question if you think that it's helpful, or answer with your own solution and accept it, so the question will be closed.

Comment: @MaxUppenkamp I'm sure you are welcome to provide your own answer and/or fix existing one.

Comment: I am experimenting right now with the Spacy Matcher, is there a way to find elements between to labels, for example verbs between two matches?